# Твои голоса "против" отнимают у тебя репутацию?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, голоса-против

Проголосовал против одного ответа, который не решает проблему (тревогой тоже отметил). Дословный "ответ" был:

> @Qwertiy, а что тогда использовать?

Вижу, что мне сняли 1 пункт репутации с пометкой "Ваш голос против". Пока писал вопрос пункт вернули, минус пропал. Что произошло? Это какой-то глюк на сайте или специальная мера, чтобы люди не занижали репутацию другим участникам сообщества?

Comment: Да, голос против ответа стоит единичку репутации)

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо. А вернули мне пункт, потому что моя тревога оказалась полезной и "ответ" удалили. Буду знать.

Comment: Если ответ был ответ, но просто не решал проблему, то тревогу помечать полезной было не по правилам.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Дословный "ответ" был : "@Qwertiy, а что тогда использовать? " Там человек хотел оставить комментарий, но у него не было репутации для этого.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH А, тогда правильно.

Comment: Русским по белому написано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

За голосование против ответов с голосующего снимается 1 балл репутации. Голосование против вопросов "бесплатно".

Вернули скорее всего из-за того, что ответ, против которого ты голосовал, был удалён.